# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) error while scraping data from understat.com

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-analysis

I am trying to scrape data of a match played between United and Sheffield United yesterday night in the premier league from understat.com. My goal is to fetch "shots per game". If you see understat.com, it has a match id for all the matches and I am using that match id to scrape the data using BS4 and requests. I have successfully located the class and got the raw data that I need to fetch in JSON format but it's giving me an error like "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)". Below is my code:

```
#Import packages and modules
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd

#Set up the url and class to scrape
#scrape the single game shot
base_url = "https://understat.com/match/"

match_id = str(input('Please enter the match id: '))
url = base_url + match_id

print(url)

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')

print(scripts)

#only the shot data
strings = scripts[1].string
print(strings)

#strip symbols so we only have the json data
index_start = strings.index("('")+1
index_end = strings.index("')")

json_data = strings[index_start:index_end]
json_data = json_data.encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape')

#convert string to json format
data = json.loads(json_data)
print(data)
```

Shots strings that I am trying to fetch:
var shotsData   = JSON.parse('\x7B\x22h\x22\x3A\x5B\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401340\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2210\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22MissedShots\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.8390000152587891\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.5379999923706055\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.08287161588668823\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Marcus\x20Rashford\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x22556\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22RightFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3A\x22Aaron\x20Wan\x2DBissaka\x22,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Pass\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401342\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2216\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22BlockedShot\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.9230000305175782\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.705999984741211\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.04452449828386307\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Mason\x20Greenwood\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x227490\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22LeftFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3A\x22Bruno\x20Fernandes\x22,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Chipped\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401344\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2226\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22SavedShot\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.74\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.37900001525878907\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.019290726631879807\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Mason\x20Greenwood\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x227490\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22LeftFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3A\x22Aaron\x20Wan\x2DBissaka\x22,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Pass\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401345\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2227\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22BlockedShot\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.8930000305175781\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.34900001525878904\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.07055725157260895\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Mason\x20Greenwood\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x227490\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22RightFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3A\x22Aaron\x20Wan\x2DBissaka\x22,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Pass\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401346\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2229\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22MissedShots\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.919000015258789\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.46599998474121096\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.04169069603085518\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Harry\x20Maguire\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x221687\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22FromCorner\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22Head\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3Anull,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Foul\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401347\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2238\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22BlockedShot\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.7169999694824218\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.4370000076293945\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.016049593687057495\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Bruno\x20Fernandes\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x221228\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22RightFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3A\x22Paul\x20Pogba\x22,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Pass\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401348\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2240\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22SavedShot\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.9330000305175781\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.485\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.0721256285905838\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Anthony\x20Martial\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x22553\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22Head\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3A\x22Bruno\x20Fernandes\x22,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Pass\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401349\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2248\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22MissedShots\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.925\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.35700000762939454\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.27813461422920227\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Mason\x20Greenwood\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x227490\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22RightFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3A\x22Bruno\x20Fernandes\x22,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Pass\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401350\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2251\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22BlockedShot\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.769000015258789\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.35200000762939454\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.019760465249419212\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Aaron\x20Wan\x2DBissaka\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x225584\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22RightFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3Anull,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22None\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401352\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2261\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22SavedShot\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.6830000305175781\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.5070000076293946\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.032827332615852356\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Marcus\x20Rashford\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x22556\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22DirectFreekick\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22RightFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3Anull,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Standard\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401353\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2263\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22BlockedShot\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.77\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.6519999694824219\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.061657458543777466\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Bruno\x20Fernandes\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x221228\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22DirectFreekick\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22RightFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3Anull,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Standard\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401354\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2263\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22Goal\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.9180000305175782\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.51\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.04361902177333832\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Harry\x20Maguire\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x221687\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22FromCorner\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22Head\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3A\x22Alex\x20Telles\x22,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Aerial\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401357\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2276\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22BlockedShot\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.7609999847412109\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.6780000305175782\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.016254646703600883\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Alex\x20Telles\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x221828\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22LeftFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3Anull,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22None\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401358\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2276\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22MissedShots\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.924000015258789\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.5070000076293946\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.10926949232816696\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Paul\x20Pogba\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x221740\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22FromCorner\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22Head\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3A\x22Alex\x20Telles\x22,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Cross\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401359\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2281\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22MissedShots\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.8630000305175781\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.5570000076293945\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.06367684155702591\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Edinson\x20Cavani\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x223294\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22LeftFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3Anull,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22None\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401360\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2285\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22BlockedShot\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.86\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.775\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.02079056017100811\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Bruno\x20Fernandes\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22h\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x221228\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22FromCorner\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22RightFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3A\x22Luke\x20Shaw\x22,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Pass\x22\x7D\x5D,\x22a\x22\x3A\x5B\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401341\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2215\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22SavedShot\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.8690000152587891\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.5479999923706055\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.12690183520317078\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Billy\x20Sharp\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22a\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x227712\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22LeftFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3A\x22John\x20Fleck\x22,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Throughball\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401343\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2222\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22Goal\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.98\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.49400001525878906\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.15722613036632538\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Kean\x20Bryan\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22a\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x229163\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22FromCorner\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22Head\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3A\x22John\x20Fleck\x22,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Cross\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401351\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2255\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22MissedShots\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.8430000305175781\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.29600000381469727\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.0439084991812706\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22David\x20McGoldrick\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22a\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x227711\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22RightFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3A\x22George\x20Baldock\x22,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Pass\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401355\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2273\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22BlockedShot\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.875\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.3609999847412109\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.07747054845094681\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Oliver\x20Burke\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22a\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x225256\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22RightFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3A\x22John\x20Lundstram\x22,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Pass\x22\x7D,\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x22401356\x22,\x22minute\x22\x3A\x2273\x22,\x22result\x22\x3A\x22Goal\x22,\x22X\x22\x3A\x220.8769999694824219\x22,\x22Y\x22\x3A\x220.3079999923706055\x22,\x22xG\x22\x3A\x220.28404054045677185\x22,\x22player\x22\x3A\x22Oliver\x20Burke\x22,\x22h_a\x22\x3A\x22a\x22,\x22player_id\x22\x3A\x225256\x22,\x22situation\x22\x3A\x22OpenPlay\x22,\x22season\x22\x3A\x222020\x22,\x22shotType\x22\x3A\x22RightFoot\x22,\x22match_id\x22\x3A\x2214628\x22,\x22h_team\x22\x3A\x22Manchester\x20United\x22,\x22a_team\x22\x3A\x22Sheffield\x20United\x22,\x22h_goals\x22\x3A\x221\x22,\x22a_goals\x22\x3A\x222\x22,\x22date\x22\x3A\x222021\x2D01\x2D27\x2020\x3A15\x3A00\x22,\x22player_assisted\x22\x3A\x22John\x20Lundstram\x22,\x22lastAction\x22\x3A\x22Pass\x22\x7D\x5D\x7D')

Can anyone help me debug the code so I can fetch the data in JSON format?

Comment: can you print `json_data`, putting its content between delimiters of your choice, like
`print("**{json_data}**")` just to see if it starts or is followed by line returns or whitespace

Comment: Please see I have updated the question with complete strings of shots and I am using "('"+1 because that's my starting index to fetch the data. @JulesG.M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `json_data` as a string starts with the `'{`. The start index you want is actually one more index value ahead at the `{`, so you want to add 2, not 1 to the index start:

`index_start = strings.index("('")+2` instead of `index_start = strings.index("('")+1`

```
#Import packages and modules
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd

#Set up the url and class to scrape
#scrape the single game shot
base_url = "https://understat.com/match/"

match_id = str(input('Please enter the match id: '))
#match_id = '14628'
url = base_url + match_id

print(url)

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')

print(scripts)

#only the shot data
strings = scripts[1].string
print(strings)

#strip symbols so we only have the json data
index_start = strings.index("('")+2   # <--- CHANGED HERE
index_end = strings.index("')")

json_data = strings[index_start:index_end]
json_data = json_data.encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape')

#convert string to json format
data = json.loads(json_data)
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'h': [{'id': '401340', 'minute': '10', 'result': 'MissedShots', 'X': '0.8390000152587891', 'Y': '0.5379999923706055', 'xG': '0.08287161588668823', 'player': 'Marcus Rashford', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '556', 'situation': 'OpenPlay', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'RightFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': 'Aaron Wan-Bissaka', 'lastAction': 'Pass'}, {'id': '401342', 'minute': '16', 'result': 'BlockedShot', 'X': '0.9230000305175782', 'Y': '0.705999984741211', 'xG': '0.04452449828386307', 'player': 'Mason Greenwood', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '7490', 'situation': 'OpenPlay', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'LeftFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': 'Bruno Fernandes', 'lastAction': 'Chipped'}, {'id': '401344', 'minute': '26', 'result': 'SavedShot', 'X': '0.74', 'Y': '0.37900001525878907', 'xG': '0.019290726631879807', 'player': 'Mason Greenwood', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '7490', 'situation': 'OpenPlay', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'LeftFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': 'Aaron Wan-Bissaka', 'lastAction': 'Pass'}, {'id': '401345', 'minute': '27', 'result': 'BlockedShot', 'X': '0.8930000305175781', 'Y': '0.34900001525878904', 'xG': '0.07055725157260895', 'player': 'Mason Greenwood', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '7490', 'situation': 'OpenPlay', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'RightFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': 'Aaron Wan-Bissaka', 'lastAction': 'Pass'}, {'id': '401346', 'minute': '29', 'result': 'MissedShots', 'X': '0.919000015258789', 'Y': '0.46599998474121096', 'xG': '0.04169069603085518', 'player': 'Harry Maguire', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '1687', 'situation': 'FromCorner', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'Head', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': None, 'lastAction': 'Foul'}, {'id': '401347', 'minute': '38', 'result': 'BlockedShot', 'X': '0.7169999694824218', 'Y': '0.4370000076293945', 'xG': '0.016049593687057495', 'player': 'Bruno Fernandes', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '1228', 'situation': 'OpenPlay', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'RightFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': 'Paul Pogba', 'lastAction': 'Pass'}, {'id': '401348', 'minute': '40', 'result': 'SavedShot', 'X': '0.9330000305175781', 'Y': '0.485', 'xG': '0.0721256285905838', 'player': 'Anthony Martial', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '553', 'situation': 'OpenPlay', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'Head', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': 'Bruno Fernandes', 'lastAction': 'Pass'}, {'id': '401349', 'minute': '48', 'result': 'MissedShots', 'X': '0.925', 'Y': '0.35700000762939454', 'xG': '0.27813461422920227', 'player': 'Mason Greenwood', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '7490', 'situation': 'OpenPlay', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'RightFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': 'Bruno Fernandes', 'lastAction': 'Pass'}, {'id': '401350', 'minute': '51', 'result': 'BlockedShot', 'X': '0.769000015258789', 'Y': '0.35200000762939454', 'xG': '0.019760465249419212', 'player': 'Aaron Wan-Bissaka', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '5584', 'situation': 'OpenPlay', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'RightFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': None, 'lastAction': 'None'}, {'id': '401352', 'minute': '61', 'result': 'SavedShot', 'X': '0.6830000305175781', 'Y': '0.5070000076293946', 'xG': '0.032827332615852356', 'player': 'Marcus Rashford', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '556', 'situation': 'DirectFreekick', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'RightFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': None, 'lastAction': 'Standard'}, {'id': '401353', 'minute': '63', 'result': 'BlockedShot', 'X': '0.77', 'Y': '0.6519999694824219', 'xG': '0.061657458543777466', 'player': 'Bruno Fernandes', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '1228', 'situation': 'DirectFreekick', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'RightFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': None, 'lastAction': 'Standard'}, {'id': '401354', 'minute': '63', 'result': 'Goal', 'X': '0.9180000305175782', 'Y': '0.51', 'xG': '0.04361902177333832', 'player': 'Harry Maguire', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '1687', 'situation': 'FromCorner', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'Head', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': 'Alex Telles', 'lastAction': 'Aerial'}, {'id': '401357', 'minute': '76', 'result': 'BlockedShot', 'X': '0.7609999847412109', 'Y': '0.6780000305175782', 'xG': '0.016254646703600883', 'player': 'Alex Telles', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '1828', 'situation': 'OpenPlay', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'LeftFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': None, 'lastAction': 'None'}, {'id': '401358', 'minute': '76', 'result': 'MissedShots', 'X': '0.924000015258789', 'Y': '0.5070000076293946', 'xG': '0.10926949232816696', 'player': 'Paul Pogba', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '1740', 'situation': 'FromCorner', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'Head', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': 'Alex Telles', 'lastAction': 'Cross'}, {'id': '401359', 'minute': '81', 'result': 'MissedShots', 'X': '0.8630000305175781', 'Y': '0.5570000076293945', 'xG': '0.06367684155702591', 'player': 'Edinson Cavani', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '3294', 'situation': 'OpenPlay', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'LeftFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': None, 'lastAction': 'None'}, {'id': '401360', 'minute': '85', 'result': 'BlockedShot', 'X': '0.86', 'Y': '0.775', 'xG': '0.02079056017100811', 'player': 'Bruno Fernandes', 'h_a': 'h', 'player_id': '1228', 'situation': 'FromCorner', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'RightFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': 'Luke Shaw', 'lastAction': 'Pass'}], 'a': [{'id': '401341', 'minute': '15', 'result': 'SavedShot', 'X': '0.8690000152587891', 'Y': '0.5479999923706055', 'xG': '0.12690183520317078', 'player': 'Billy Sharp', 'h_a': 'a', 'player_id': '7712', 'situation': 'OpenPlay', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'LeftFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': 'John Fleck', 'lastAction': 'Throughball'}, {'id': '401343', 'minute': '22', 'result': 'Goal', 'X': '0.98', 'Y': '0.49400001525878906', 'xG': '0.15722613036632538', 'player': 'Kean Bryan', 'h_a': 'a', 'player_id': '9163', 'situation': 'FromCorner', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'Head', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': 'John Fleck', 'lastAction': 'Cross'}, {'id': '401351', 'minute': '55', 'result': 'MissedShots', 'X': '0.8430000305175781', 'Y': '0.29600000381469727', 'xG': '0.0439084991812706', 'player': 'David McGoldrick', 'h_a': 'a', 'player_id': '7711', 'situation': 'OpenPlay', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'RightFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': 'George Baldock', 'lastAction': 'Pass'}, {'id': '401355', 'minute': '73', 'result': 'BlockedShot', 'X': '0.875', 'Y': '0.3609999847412109', 'xG': '0.07747054845094681', 'player': 'Oliver Burke', 'h_a': 'a', 'player_id': '5256', 'situation': 'OpenPlay', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'RightFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': 'John Lundstram', 'lastAction': 'Pass'}, {'id': '401356', 'minute': '73', 'result': 'Goal', 'X': '0.8769999694824219', 'Y': '0.3079999923706055', 'xG': '0.28404054045677185', 'player': 'Oliver Burke', 'h_a': 'a', 'player_id': '5256', 'situation': 'OpenPlay', 'season': '2020', 'shotType': 'RightFoot', 'match_id': '14628', 'h_team': 'Manchester United', 'a_team': 'Sheffield United', 'h_goals': '1', 'a_goals': '2', 'date': '2021-01-27 20:15:00', 'player_assisted': 'John Lundstram', 'lastAction': 'Pass'}]}
```

Also you could replace:

```
#strip symbols so we only have the json data
index_start = strings.index("('")+2   # <--- CHANGED HERE
index_end = strings.index("')")

json_data = strings[index_start:index_end]
```

with:

```
#strip symbols so we only have the json data
json_data = strings.split("('", 1)[-1].rsplit("')",2)[0]
```